# Basic troubles with scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

I have learnt a few languages in the past and I thought it would be a good I idea to learn C.

I am having a little trouble with scanf...

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){

    char name[20];
    char yn;

    printf("Welcome to Benjamin's first C programme! \n\n");

    printf("What is your name? \t"); scanf("%s", name); printf("\n");
    printf("Is your name %s? [y/n]", name); scanf("%s", yn);

}
```

I am having trouble with: `scanf("%s", yn)`

Comment: Consider `char yn[2]; scanf("%1s", yn);`.  The biggest road block learners have is not realizing that '\n' is not typically consumed until the next `scanf()`.  Recommend to look into `fgets()/sscanf()` for user IO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do the following:

```
printf("Is your name %s? [y/n]", name); scanf("%c", &yn);
```

What the new scanf does is says "expect a char" and put it in the address of yn

Answer (score 2):

To read into a char use

```
scanf("%c",&yn);
```

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` can only take pointers as parameters. `name` is an array so its a pointer by definition, but `yn` is not. You have to cast it as `&yn`, *a pointer to `yn`*, in order to make `scanf()` read to it.

Also, `yn` can only hold a single `char`, not an array of chars as in `name`, so you have to tell `scanf()` you want to read a `%c` for single char, not a `%s` for null-terminated string, because if you do you will most likely overwrite the stack and run in trouble.

That being said, use `scanf("%c", &yn);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

or prepare yourself and do a simple malloc (but that's not the better choice)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){

    char name[20];
    char *yn;
    yn = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
    printf("Welcome to Benjamin's first C programme! \n\n");

    printf("What is your name? \t"); scanf("%s", name); printf("\n");

    printf("Is your name %s? [y/n]", name); scanf("%s", yn);

}
```